# How to reset flip flop in ATF16V8?

Tags: dram, z80

I'm designing a Z80 microcomputer with dynamic memory (DRAM), and I want to control the memory with 3 chips; an ATF16V8 Generic-Array Logic, and 2 74LS157 quad 2:1 multiplexers. The logic diagram of the circuit to be embedded in the GAL is already done, but I have one problem: How do you reset a D-Flip-flop in the ATF16V8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about 'registered' mode where the macrocell has a D flip flop, you can't. The output registers are only reset at power on, and do not have programmable Set or Reset inputs. At run time a logical input combination (product/sum term) can be clocked into the D input, and the Clock or Output Enable inputs can be controlled from an another output by wiring it to them externally (though only globally to all flip flops).

(From [ATF16V8B datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-0364-PLD-ATF16V8B-8BQ-8BQL-Datasheet.pdf))

[image]

If you can't modify your logic to get around this limitation (eg. by clocking the reset state in via the D input, or making a latch instead of a D flip flop) then the easiest solution might be to add a separate IC which has a full function D flip flop in it (eg. 74HCT74).

Comment: Thanks for the insight! Since I need inverted and non-inverted CAS outputs (the signal that's being generated by this latch), the best idea might be to set up a bistable latch with 2 of the 8 output pins. None of the internal "registered" flip flops will be used, which means the CLK input will not matter, so the clock signal (1MHz) will be fed in through one of the general-purpose inputs, as I'm only using 5 of them.

Comment: When you have finished your design can you provide link to it? Or perhaps answer the question yourself so we can see it here. I'm curious to see how you do it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution, thank you @Bruce Abbott

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS67G8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is a slightly modified version of the Z80 DRAM interface available at https://devster.monkeeh.com/z80/z80dram.gif, the main difference is that instead of using small pieces of several 74 series logic gates, I'm compressing all of the logic into a single ATF16V8 (It's still manufactured for some reason). If all goes well, I
want to drive 2 16K memory banks (32K total) from this one chip. That will leave room for up to 32K ROM, which is more than enough.